# Having troubles multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I have a `HashMap`. Each String has an integer with it.
I made a check thread to send a request to a web server and get an answer.

```
int io = (Main.LIST_TOTAL / Main.THREAD_TOTAL);
int ioe = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= Main.THREAD_TOTAL; i++) {
    ioe += io;
    CheckThread ct = new CheckThread(ioe, Main.THREAD_LAST);
    ct.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    al.add(ct);
    ct.start();
    Main.THREAD_LAST = ioe;
}
for (CheckThread ct : al) {
        ct.join();
    }
```

That's the code I used to divide the numbers. E.G. 1 - 10 for 1st thread. 11 - 20 to 2nd thread.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = ii; i < this.i; i++) {
            if (this.check(Main.hm.get(i))) {
                doSomething();
            } else {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Main.LIST_FAILED++;
    }
}
```

I'm having a lot of misses. I think that there is a problem with the way I divided the list to check.

Edit:

> Results - 1k
>
> Public - 342 Private - 645 Failed - 0 Percentage Private - 64.5% Time
>   Spent Checking - 8 seconds Threads Used - 100 Combos Per Second - 125
>
> Results - 50k
>
> Public - 5733 Private - 11628 Failed - 71 Percentage Private - 23.256%
>   Time Spent Checking - 371 seconds Threads Used - 100 Combos Per Second
>   - 134

Comment: So, what do you need help with?

Comment: I need to fix the loss. The code doesn't iterate through all the data. E.G. I want 5k requests. I get around 3k back.

Comment: Please provide us with all required code for reproducing the problem and the expected output. Your problem is still unclear to me.

Comment: I'd suggest first reducing your problem to a single thread until you have fully debugged it. *After* you have the logic working, in a single thread, *then* you can easily spin-off that logic to a child. ### Also, be very sure that you have provided some means for the parent to wait until the child has finished his work.

Comment: I edited OP. I used Thread#join to make the main thread wait for all the threads to finish. I think the problem isn't because of how I multi threaded it, It's something to do with the for loops. I'm very confused because this works for small lists. E.G. 100. But when I try to use a list that's big(500k). It misses quite a lot. Give me a few minutes and I will edit the code with results.

Comment: Stop trying to do your threads by hand.  Read about `ExecutorService`.  Create a `Callable` class that performs operations on the desired subset of the data, instantiate one of your Callable classes for each subset and store them in a List.  Then let the ExecutorService worry about the threading.

Comment: The problem rn is that the threads just stop after a certain amount of requests? It works perfectly with low lists, but when it gets higher it just stops... This just breaks all my logic lol.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve